# PHP & MySQLi OOP - Why is my logged in variable not being set to true?

Tags: php, class, oop, mysqli, authentication

The database class methods are working correctly as the user is authenticated correctly. The session is being set to the correct user id but the logged in variable is not being set? Var dump returns false but it should be getting set to true after the login method is run.

login.php

```
<?php 

//session is started in the initialize file and all required files are included
require_once('includes/init.php');

// set initial values so that input values using username and password variables do not return undefined as well as the error variable
$username = "";
$password = "";
$error = "";

if($session->isLoggedIn()) {
    redirect('index.php');
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);

    $foundUser = User::verify($username, $password);
    if ($foundUser) {
        $session->login($foundUser);
        redirect('index.php');
    } else {
        $error = "Combination incorrect";
    }
}

?>
```

session.php

```
<?php

// Session class allows to store session cookies so that data can be looked up without having to go back to the database
// Database objects not stored because they could get updated in the database so the cookies could become outdated

class Session {
    public $loggedIn = false;
    public $userId;

    function __contruct() {
        $this->checkLogin();
    }

    public function isLoggedIn() {
        return $this->loggedIn;
    }

    private function checkLogin() {
        if(isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
            $this->userId = $_SESSION['userId'];
            $this->loggedIn = true;
        } else {
            unset($this->userId);
            $this->loggedIn = false;
        }
    }

    public function login($user) {
        if($user) {
            $this->userId = $_SESSION['userId'] = $user->userId;
            $this->loggedIn = true;
        }
    }

    public function logout() {
        unset($_SESSION['userId']);
        unset($this->userId);
        $this->loggedIn = false;
    }
}

$session = new Session();

?>
```

user.php

```
<?php

class User {

    public $userId;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $email;
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;
    public $access;
    public $active;

    public static function getUsers() {
        return self::getBySQL("SELECT * FROM users");
    }

    public static function getUserId($id=0) {
        global $db;
        $resultArray = self::getBySQL("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId={$id}");
        return !empty($resultArray) ? array_shift($resultArray) : false;
    }

    public static function getBySQL($sql) {
        global $db;
        $result = $db->query($sql);
        $objArray = array();
        while ($row = $db->fetchArray($result)) {
            $objArray[] = self::instantiate($row);
        }
        return $objArray;
    }

    public function getName() {
        if (isset($this->firstname) && isset($this->lastname)) {
            return $this->firstname . " " . $this->lastname;
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    private static function instantiate($record) {
        $object = new self;

        foreach($record as $attr=>$value){
            if($object->hasAttr($attr)) {
                $object->$attr = $value;
            }
        }
        return $object;
    }

    private function hasAttr($attr) {
        $objectVars = get_object_vars($this);
        return array_key_exists($attr, $objectVars);
    }

    public static function verify($username, $password) {
        global $db;
        $username = $db->prepare($username);
        $password = $db->prepare($password);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}' AND userpass = '{$password}'";
        $resultArray = self::getBySQL($sql);
        return !empty($resultArray) ? array_shift($resultArray) : false;
    }
}

?>
```

database.php

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

class Database {
    private $connection;

    function __construct() {
        $this->connect();
    }

    public function connect() {
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die("Database connection failed: " . 
               mysqli_connect_error() . 
               " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
            );
        }
    }

    public function disconnect() {
        if(isset($this->connection)) {
            mysqli_close($this->connection);
            unset($this->connection);
        }
    }

    public function query($sql) {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql);
        if (!$result) {
            die("Database query failed.");
        } 
        return $result;
    }

    public function prepare($data) {
        $escString = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $data);
        return $escString;
    }

    public function fetchArray($results) {
        return mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
    }
}

$db = new Database();

?>
```

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yeah don't worry I'm big on security so I will eventually add the protection but atm just trying to get everything working correctly

Comment: I hate when people say *"I'm not that far along..."* or *"This site will not be public..."* or *"It's only for school, so security doesn't matter..."*. If teachers and professors are not talking about security from day one, they're doing it wrong. Challenge them. They're teaching sloppy and dangerous coding practices which students will have to unlearn later. I also hate it when folks say, *"I'll add security later..."*. If you don't have time to do it right the first time, when will you find the time to add it later? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is not able to keep variable values between requests. This means that each time your script is called, the $bool-variable will be set to false. If you want to keep the value between requests you have to use sessions or, if you want the variable shared between sessions, some caching mechanism like APC or Memcache.